# Looking for legacy code to demonstrate TDD

Tags: open-source, c++, software-testing

I'd like to run a workshop in our company about applying TDD practices to existing legacy code. I'm looking for open source code which would match our needs:

- Should be cross-platform C++ (Windows+Mac minimum)
- Should be an untested spaghetti mess...
- ... but not to big, with not to many external dependencies. So, for example openssl is not really valid -

I'm having trouble finding a piece of code matching this - but maybe somebody could recommend something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be a untested mess, but claims cross-platform and has a function which is easy to understand:

Chenard Chess  http://cosinekitty.com/chenard/

I have no specific experience with this.

Answer (score 1):

The legacy code retreat codebase matches my needs very well: https://github.com/jbrains/trivia